# Fastest way to fill dictionary from list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

Here is my list:

```
animallist=["bird","cow","chicken","horse"]
```

I want to create a dictionary, with these animals as keys and values determined by some_funtion. My script:

```
def some_function(eachanimal):
    #do some stuff with the entry, for example:
    return eachanimal+"_value"

animallist=["bird","cow","chicken","horse"]
mydict={}
for eachanimal in animallist:
    mydict[eachanimal]=some_function(eachanimal)
```

This creates mydict, which is:

```
{'bird': 'bird_value',
'cow': 'cow_value',
'chicken': 'chicken_value',
'horse': 'horse_value'}
```

How can I do this faster or more compactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty sure it is not faster, but I find it at least more elegant

```
mydict = {x: some_function(x) for x in animallist}
```

Answer (score 2):

you could use a [dict-comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=comprehension#dictionaries) to make it more compact:

```
dct = {animal: f"{animal}_value" for animal in animallist}
```

Comment: The elegance of this dictionary comprehension is just simply amazing... Very efficient as well.

Answer (score 2):

Using `dict`

**Ex:**

```
animallist=["bird","cow","chicken","horse"]
print( dict((i, i+"_value") for i in animallist) )
```

**Output:**

```
{'chicken': 'chicken_value', 'horse': 'horse_value', 'bird': 'bird_value', 'cow': 'cow_value'}
```

Answer (score 1):

To make it more compact, dict comprehension -

```
{eachanimal:some_function(eachanimal) for eachanimal in animallist}
```

Using `timeit` to time code bits -

```
In [1]: s = """\
    ...: animallist=["bird","cow","chicken","horse"]
    ...: def some_function(eachanimal):
    ...:     return eachanimal+"_value"
    ...: animallist=["bird","cow","chicken","horse"]
    ...: mydict={}
    ...: for eachanimal in animallist:
    ...:     mydict[eachanimal]=some_function(eachanimal)
    ...: """

In [2]: min(timeit.repeat(s, repeat=5))
Out[3]: 0.9832079410552979

In [4]: s = """\
    ...: animallist=["bird","cow","chicken","horse"]
    ...: dict((eachanimal,eachanimal+'_value') for eachanimal in animallist)
    ...: """

In [5]: min(timeit.repeat(s, repeat=5))
Out[6]: 1.5261759757995605

In [7]: s = """\
    ...: animallist=["bird","cow","chicken","horse"]
    ...: def some_function(eachanimal):
    ...:     return eachanimal+"_value"
    ...: {eachanimal:some_function(eachanimal) for eachanimal in animallist}
    ...: """

In [8]: min(timeit.repeat(s, repeat=5))
Out[9]: 1.1118130683898926

In [10]: s = """\
    ...: animallist=["bird","cow","chicken","horse"]
    ...: dict(zip(animallist,[s + "_value" for s in animallist]))
    ...: """

In [11]: min(timeit.repeat(s, repeat=5))
Out[12]: 1.603926181793213

In [13]: s = """\
    ...: animallist=["bird","cow","chicken","horse"]
    ...: {eachanimal:eachanimal+'_value' for eachanimal in animallist}
    ...: """

In [14]: min(timeit.repeat(s, repeat=5))
Out[15]: 0.6992459297180176
```

So on my system which is `i5-3437U CPU @ 1.90GHz, 8GB RAM`, it looks like

```
{eachanimal:eachanimal+'_value' for eachanimal in animallist}
```

is actually **faster** *and* **compact** than your version

Answer (score 1):

```
animallist=["bird","cow","chicken","horse"]
dict(zip(animallist,[s + "_value" for s in animallist]))
```

But I like Rakesh's answer !